# Validate mat-autocomplete is object

Tags: angular

I'm new in Angular. I have a form in html:

```
   <form class="input-form" [formGroup]='terminalsForm'>
      <mat-form-field class="form-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="From" [matAutocomplete]="auto" formControlName='terminalInput' required>

      </mat-form-field>

      <span>Your choice is: {{terminalsForm.get('terminalInput').value | json}}</span>

      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let terminal of (filteredTerminals)?.results" [value]="terminal">
            <span>{{ terminal.name }}, {{terminal.city}}</span>
          </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </form>
```

It works fine and span indicate me if I selected an object or not (it returns a json with id included if I autocomplited object). How can I validate this field with select required? I need to pass terminal Id next so not selecting is supposed to be a validation error. Thanks!

Comment: you can validate it using "terminalInput" right ? what is the problem here ?

Comment: @JithinScaria the problem is that I'm a newbie and try to find a working snippet to discover how it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Updated on 24-01-2019**

As per comments from [@D. Make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54328024/validate-mat-autocomplete-is-object/54328246?noredirect=1#comment95475126_54328246), custom validator function is needed in the `input`.

So, I have updated the code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kdym4u).

I have added a new validator called `forbiddenNamesValidator`, which allow users to enter names only from suggested values. It's been added to `myControl` like below:

**autocomplete-simple-example.ts**

```
...
constructor() {
    this.myControl.setValidators(forbiddenNamesValidator(this.options));
}
...
export function forbiddenNamesValidator(names: string[]): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    // below findIndex will check if control.value is equal to one of our options or not
    const index = names.findIndex(name => {
      return (new RegExp('\^' + name + '\$')).test(control.value);
    });
    return index < 0 ? { 'forbiddenNames': { value: control.value } } : null;
  };
}
```

Ad in html, it's handled like below:

```html
...
<mat-error *ngIf="myControl.hasError('forbiddenNames')">
      You should enter value from suggested one only. <strong>'{{myControl.errors.forbiddenNames.value}}'</strong> is not allowed.
</mat-error>
...
```

**Original Answer**

To handle validation errors, you have to attach it to `input[required]` inside `mat-form-field`:

```html
<mat-form-field class="form-full-width">
    <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Terminals" formControlName="terminal" required [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let terminal of (filteredTerminals)?.results" [value]="terminal">
            <span>{{ terminal.name }}, {{terminal.city}}</span>
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

You can also check Angular Material Team's official example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jnynnmxmnex?file=app%2Fautocomplete-simple-example.html).

Comment: I already have a 'required' in my input. I get remote data for autocomplete so when user type Lond back-end send json with ids and names (for example London). I need to catch an object and raise an error if object not selected. If I select object London and then make Londo, I have no object anymore but there is no validation error which i need.

Comment: Did you try by just focusing on input and not selecting any value? Can you upload your code on stackblitz?

Comment: See this example : https://stackblitz.com/angular/jnynnmxmnex, just add `required` to input and you would see `input` turning to red when no value selected.

Comment: But the problem is that there are only [One, Two, Three] and it does not turn red when I type Four, Five or even Thr. Thats what I need.

Comment: In that case you need a custom validator. Check here https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators

Comment: I have updated code and answer above, please check now.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, my autocomplete get data from the server-side (arrays of objects), so I've created this simple function that validates that the selected value is an object and different from null, with this is enough for me.

I hope that this can be useful for someone.

```
export function forbiddenObjectValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
        return typeof control.value !== 'object' || control.value === null ? { 'forbiddenObject': true } : null;
}
```